# How to change the default project that comes in the One Click App for Ruby on Rails image from DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, digital-ocean

I need to deploy my own app, I am using a image of Ruby on Rails One click app and I need to change the rails_project which comes by default to my own Application from a repository, but I cannot see in the documentation of DigitalOcean. How I can do this?

I already tried to move some configurations in the files /etc/unicorn.conf and / etc / nginx / sites-enabled / rails but it did not work for me, I still get the error 502

I need to know what changes I need to make and what files I need to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this article for more info about deploy: [Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma).
Ruby on Rails One click app droplet make steps 1-5. So you can start from the step 6.

Default entry point to your droplet is Nginx. Check `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. That gives you more info about a problem. If there all is ok check unicorn log `/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log`. Those two files let you know what doesn't work. Also, don't forget to restart Nginx after any configuration changes: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`(`sudo system nginx restart`) - read all messages after that command.

Comment: ok but in that tutorial they use Puma and the One Click app install unircorn, this is a problem ? or nothing happens ?

Comment: No, that is not a problem. Just use capistrano\unicorn as in link https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn instead capistrano\puma. But I still recommend trying first play with Puma(Unicorn configuration sometime hard). So, Unicorn as Puma just a gem that will be installed automatically when you shall deploying

Answer (score 5):

The latest one-click-app image of Rails app on Digital Ocean comes with puma and nginx. I was also trying to deploy my own app instead of the example app and access it from the droplet ip address.

Just change the following files/configurations to get your app deployed instead of the example app:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails
/etc/systemd/system/rails.service
```

Then run the following commands to restart the services and you're all set.

```
systemctl restart rails.service
systemctl daemon-reload
service nginx restart
```

Comment: thank you so much, this can help me in another project.